# Yarn Workspaces: How to satisfy peer dependency?

Tags: yarn-workspaces, peer-dependencies

I just started using Yarn workspaces and have two packages defined, let's call them Alpha and Beta. Beta depends on Alpha.

Alpha has a peer dependency for `somelib@^1.2.3`, so I added `somelib@^1.2.3` as dependency to Beta's `package.json`.

When installing, I get the warning

```
> alpha@0.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "somelib@^1.2.3".
```

I would assume by adding `somelib@^1.2.3` as dependency to Beta, the peer dependency is satisfied. Why do I still get a warning, how do I satisfy the peer dependency?

Comment: Take a look on this https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5347

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Are you implying this is a bug in Yarn? From the issue I get the feeling it's more of a user error.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue and noticed that the warnings go away when adding the peer dependencies to the root package.json (even though that's not where they belong). So I'm assuming it's a bug in Yarn.